# Bounding the difference of squares of quotients

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ with $c,d > 0$. Assume that $|a-b| < \epsilon_1$ and $|c-d| < \epsilon_2$.

What can be said about $|(a/c)^2 - (b/d)^2|$?

What I tried is the following:

\begin{align*}
|(a/c)^2 - (b/d)^2| & \leq | a/c - b/d | \cdot |  a/c + b/d | \\
& =  | a/c - b/c + b/c - b/d | \cdot | a/c + b/d | \\
& \leq  | (a-b)/c | + |b| |1/c - 1/d | \cdot |  a/c + b/d | \\
& \leq  \epsilon_1/c  + |b|/(cd) |d-c | \cdot |  a/c + b/d | \\
& \leq  \epsilon_1/c  + \epsilon_2 |b|/(cd)  \cdot |  a/c + b/d | 
\end{align*}

Is it possible to further improve this bound? Especially the last factor $|  a/c + b/d | $ troubles me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should bother you.  The $cd$ in the denominator should bother you also.  If $c,d$ are small enough, $cd$ can be huge.  Let us take $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=.0001$ just for fun.  Then we can have $a=b=1, c=.0001, d=10^{-12}$  Then $|(\frac ac)^2-(\frac bd)^2|=|10^8-10^{24}| \approx 10^{24}$  It should be clear that we can make this as large as we want even if the $\epsilon$s are very small.

Comment: In fact, the bound given is even worse; while the actual 'error' depends 'only' quadratically on $1/c, 1/d$, the bound does cubically. The estimated error with the numbers given in this answer is $10^4 + 10^{16}*(10^{12} + 10^4) \approx 10^{28}$. This happens in the second inequality.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. is there a way to get the bound sharper?